# not able to add custom block in cart page above coupon block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cart, xml

i am adding the block through xml on cart page. i searching a lot but could not find the find the solution where i am getting wrong.

```
<checkout_cart_index>

    <reference name="checkout.cart">

            <block type="test/test" before="coupon"   template="test/cart_test.phtml" />

    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

when i and  the block is added to cart page but i want to add before the coupon block any help will be appreciated.

Comment: call your custom block before coupon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that was work for me

```
<?php echo  Mage::app()->getLayout()
            ->createBlock('test/test')
            ->setTemplate('test/test.phtml')
            ->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try like this,

```
<reference name="checkout.cart">

   <block type="test/test" before="coupon" name="custom-block"  template="test/cart_test.phtml" />

</reference>
```

call your custom block before coupon in `app\design\frontend\package\theme\template\checkout\cart.phtml`,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('custom-block'); ?>

 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
```

Comment: i tried but it's not working for me

Comment: check your custom block and template is correctly defined

Comment: yes if i change <reference name="content"> . it is showing

Comment: @QaisarSatti  Have you put the $this->getChildHtml('custom-block');  in your cart.phtml

Comment: yes i put it but it is not showing anything..

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
            <block type="test/test" before="checkout.cart.coupon"   template="test/cart_test.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no it is not working..

Comment: Hope you have cleared cache as well.

Comment: still not luck :(

Answer (score 1):

If the XML isn't working for you then the easiet way to inject your cms block is the php code snippet.

Try the following and it will inject the block:

- Open your cart.phtml file and locate the div/html section where you would like your block to appear and paste the following code there.

  > `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId("your-static-block-id")->toHtml();?>`

Comment: i am creating the ext bro

Comment: Okay, in that case, have you tried clearing your cache? Make sure it's disabled whilst your project is in dev mode. Have you also tried to inject any other block except the one you created? Is the block set to enabled? What is the scope of the static block?

Comment: it is developer mode and cache is disabled.no other block in added there.