# inserting custom block above coupon block in shopping cart

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template

How do I **insert a custom `block` right above the coupon code field in the shopping cart** by just using the `layout.xml` (without editing the template using `getChildHtml()`).

I had done it before now i just cant seem to remember the block name..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not able to add custom block in cart page above coupon block](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76435/not-able-to-add-custom-block-in-cart-page-above-coupon-block)

Comment: no, its not a duplicate, as i already checked that and no feasible solution is suggested

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in your themes local.xml and check.

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
<reference name="checkout.cart">
<block type="core/template" before="coupon" name="sample" template="sample.phtml"/>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: this doesnt place above the "discount coupon" box

Answer (score 0):

**Magento provides a placeholder for extensions or custom blocks that you can use which is called `checkout.cart.extra`** as you can see from the `cart.phtml` template:

```
<div class="col-2">
    <?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.cart.extra') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
    <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping'); endif; ?>
</div>
```

So you can totally do the following in your `local.xml` file:

```
<checkout_cart_index>
    <reference name="checkout.cart">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.cart.extra" translate="label">
            <label>Checkout Forms Extra</label>
            <block type="core/template" name="my.custom.block" template="path/to/template.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
```

Comment: i would like to do it without hardcoding into templates, I know there is wa way, i just forgot the block name

Comment: @anant well read my solution again. The template code is from the core you don't have to exit the template simply use the layout code I pasted

Comment: but it is not inserting the block right above the discount block

Comment: how to add block in admin order create page  ?  layout xml   @RaphaelatDigitalPianism

Comment: @lalitmohan that's a totally different question please create a new question

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144297/add-custom-block-to-admin-order-create-page-load